# The argument type 'BlocProvider' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget' - Cubit BlocProvider

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, bloc

I am literally pulling my hair over this because all tutorials seem to be implementing this part of code this way.
But my compiler throws the error: **The argument type 'BlocProvider' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget'.**
I am following the tutorial: [Flutter Bloc & Cubit](https://resocoder.com/2020/08/04/flutter-bloc-cubit-tutorial/)
All parts of the code work well apart from the **Main.dart** where we are supposed to add the **BlocProvider**
I am new to flutter and I have no Idea what I should do from here.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      home: BlocProvider(
        create: (context) => WeatherCubit(FakeWeatherRepository()),
        child: WeatherSearchPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The error is as seen in the attached image:
[image: attached image]

Answer (score 1):

I have mostly seen MaterialApp being the child of the BlocProvider, but this isn't the issue. I can't tell from the code shown, but my best guess is, you have a problem with `FakeWeatherRepository` and `WeatherSearchPage`, which may well cause the error of of BlocProvider not being a widget.

Are you sure both widgets are imported. The underline on the screens looks more like typo correction and not like error. But maybe you wand to remove BlocProvider and put both widgets behind `home:`  directly (either as a column or one by one) and check if they are recognized or if they still throw an error

Answer (score 0):

If anyone ever experiences this error which is uncommon,

Run the following command: `flutter pub cache repair`

Then restart both the laptop and the IDE.

This worked for me following guidance by @felangel on [github](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/1990#issuecomment-740748619)

Comment: Yes it seems to be an issue that is semi-common with dart analyzer and affects state management code, Including bloc state management code.